# Where is wrapped c/c++ object of type QPlainTextEdit deleted in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I am developing a plugin for QGIS, and have an ownership problem trying to set a QPlainTextEdit as logging handler. I use python logging package for logging. But when I try to send messages to the handler I get an error stating "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted". 
I have two classes, one for the initiating and running the plugin the other for the logging handler:

```
import logging 
... 


class myPlugin:
    def __init__(self,iface):
        <init code>
    ... 

    def loadDialog(self):
        self.dlg=MyPluginDialog()
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()

        # Set up logging to use the dlg text widget as a handler
        self.log_handler = customLogHandler(self.dlg.logText) #logText is a QPlainTextEdit
        self.log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\n %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))

        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.log_handler)

        self.dlg.runButton.pressed.connect(self.run_alg)



    def run_alg(self):
        ...
        logging.info('This is an info message')
        logging.warning('This is a warning message')
        logging.critical('This is a critical message')


class customLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, log_widget):
        super().__init__()


        self.widget = log_widget
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.textCursor().insertText(msg)

    def write(self, m):
        pass
```

When I run the plugin first time it works well. But after I close the dialog and open it again, I can't run it anymore. It keeps trowing the same error.

Can someone, please, point me to the right direction to fix this problem?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008358/4699904

Comment: +1 to Fran Raga's thread link. I experienced this same error message but in a different event (I was trying to create print layouts with Python in QGIS). I could create a print layout once, but the 2nd time I got the same error message. My solution was to include some code to check if the print layout existed and if it did, delete it before creating a new one with the same name.